# Video Download via local PHP proxy if user closes the browser

Tags: php, download

I have a php that validates downloads of large files (videos).

Example:

```
<?php
// proxy.php

// validations here
$contents=file_get_contents("video.mp4");

// headers here
echo $contents;
```

**What happens to the script execution if a user requests the file (via proxy.php) and closes the window/browser (or browse away)?**

I want to avoid the script from keep being executed (and the video from being downloaded) in limbo, when there's no user anymore.

Comment: Using `file_get_contents()` with video is quite a challenging proposition!

Comment: It's just for illustration purposes. I need to know the concept behind the http request. Not ideas for optimization.